# Происходит ли копирование при взятии подмассива?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

У меня есть большой массив в Python:

```
a = list(range(1_000_000))
```

и я хочу выбрать случайный элемент из его первых `n` элементов. Сейчас я делаю это так:

```
random_element = random.choice(a[:n])
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, будет ли здесь происходить копирование массива при взятии подмассива и вообще, насколько быстро это работает? Спасибо.

Comment: А нельзя было сгенерировать случайное число до n?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka можно, видимо так и придётся сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Срезы возвращают копию списка, это легко проверить запустив код:

```
a = list(range(1_000_000))
sub_a_5 = a[:5]
print(sub_a_5, hex(id(sub_a_5)), type(sub_a_5))

sub_a_5 = a[:5]
print(sub_a_5, hex(id(sub_a_5)), type(sub_a_5))
```

Например, у меня это выдало:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 0x2a026836248 <class 'list'>
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4] 0x2a026836288 <class 'list'>
```

---

Используя срезы, можно копию сделать:

```
copy_a = a[:]
```

Comment: Понятно, спасибо

Comment: Непонятно, как `id()` позволяет узнать, что это копия. Чисто теоретически это может оказаться какой-нибудь специальный объект-слайс, который выглядит как массив, но сам данных не хранит и ссылается на оригинальный массив. Я знаю, что в Python это не так (и проверяется это не через `id()`), но в каком-нибудь Rust — так :)